# how can i acces the next element in char** string

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

i want to pass the below character-array to a function and use it there. i want to print every this string character by character as it is, but the only character i can access is the first character of this string. i thought *string++ would give me the address of the next element and thus the next character.

```
char* string[] = {
    "Garbage,",
    "",
    "Garbage garbage",
    "Garbage garbage Garbage garbage",
    "Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage ",
    "Garbage Garbage Garbage ",
    "Garbage Garbage ",
    "",
    "Garbage ,",
    "Garbage "
};
```

that's how i'm trying to do it. so what am i doing wrong here?

```
while(**string != '\0'){
    if(**string == '\n'){
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%c\n", **string);
    *string = *(string + 1);
}
```

Comment: `string` is an array of pointers. It's not a pointer to pointer. Because of that, you cannot assign to `*string`

Comment: @klutt so how can i access each element of the string?

Comment: I would recommend using index notation. `string[line][character]` If you must use pointer notation, bear in mind that the first level of indirection will give you the line, and using `*` on that will give you the first character. `char* stringIterator = string; char* firstLine = *stringIterator; char firstChar = *firstLine++; char secondChar = *firstLine++; char* secondLine = *++stringIterator;`

Answer (score 1):

`string` is an array. It is not a modifiable lvalue by itself. (purist flamethrowers engaged).

You can use syntax similar to `*id++`, but you have to walk the array with a pointer of the appropriate type to do it.

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *string[] =
    {
        "Garbage,",
        "Garbage garbage",
        "Garbage garbage Garbage garbage",
        "Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage ",
        "Garbage Garbage Garbage ",
        "Garbage Garbage ",
        "",
        "Garbage ,",
        "Garbage "
    };

    // one way to walk with a pointer.
    const char * const *str = string;
    while (**str)
        puts(*str++);
}
```

Output

```
Garbage,
Garbage garbage
Garbage garbage Garbage garbage
Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage 
Garbage Garbage Garbage 
Garbage Garbage
```